# What version of @angular/material do I need?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I pulled a project. When I try to install `ng add @angular/material` I get:

```
    # npm resolution error report

While resolving: @angular/material-moment-adapter@13.0.0
Found: @angular/core@10.0.14
node_modules/@angular/core
  peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/animations@10.0.14
  node_modules/@angular/animations
    peerOptional @angular/animations@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
      peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/forms@10.0.14
      node_modules/@angular/forms
        @angular/forms@"~10.0.6" from the root project
        peer @angular/forms@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
        node_modules/@angular/material
          @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
      peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
      node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
        @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~10.0.6" from the root project
      peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/router@10.0.14
      node_modules/@angular/router
        @angular/router@"~10.0.6" from the root project
      @angular/platform-browser@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    @angular/animations@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/animations@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
    node_modules/@angular/material
      @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
  node_modules/@angular/cdk
    @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project
    peer @angular/cdk@"10.2.7" from @angular/material@10.2.7
    node_modules/@angular/material
      @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/common@10.0.14
  node_modules/@angular/common
    peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
    node_modules/@angular/cdk
      @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project
      peer @angular/cdk@"10.2.7" from @angular/material@10.2.7
      node_modules/@angular/material
        @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
    peer @angular/common@"10.0.14" from @angular/forms@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/forms
      @angular/forms@"~10.0.6" from the root project
      peer @angular/forms@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
      node_modules/@angular/material
        @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
    peer @angular/common@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
      peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/forms@10.0.14
      node_modules/@angular/forms
        @angular/forms@"~10.0.6" from the root project
        peer @angular/forms@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
        node_modules/@angular/material
          @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
      peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
      node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
        @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~10.0.6" from the root project
      peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/router@10.0.14
      node_modules/@angular/router
        @angular/router@"~10.0.6" from the root project
      @angular/platform-browser@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/common@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
      @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/common@"10.0.14" from @angular/router@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/router
      @angular/router@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/common@">=7.2.0" from ng2-charts@3.0.0-rc.3
    node_modules/ng2-charts
      ng2-charts@"^3.0.0-rc.3" from the root project
    @angular/common@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
    node_modules/@angular/material
      @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/forms@10.0.14
  node_modules/@angular/forms
    @angular/forms@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/forms@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
    node_modules/@angular/material
      @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser@10.0.14
  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/forms@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/forms
      @angular/forms@"~10.0.6" from the root project
      peer @angular/forms@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
      node_modules/@angular/material
        @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
      @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/platform-browser@"10.0.14" from @angular/router@10.0.14
    node_modules/@angular/router
      @angular/router@"~10.0.6" from the root project
    @angular/platform-browser@"~10.0.6" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~10.0.6" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/router@10.0.14
  node_modules/@angular/router
    @angular/router@"~10.0.6" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@">=7.2.0" from ng2-charts@3.0.0-rc.3
  node_modules/ng2-charts
    ng2-charts@"^3.0.0-rc.3" from the root project
  @angular/core@"~10.0.6" from the root project
  peer @angular/core@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/material@10.2.7
  node_modules/@angular/material
    @angular/material@"10.2.7" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@13.0.0
node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
  @angular/material-moment-adapter@"^13.0.0" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@14.2.12
node_modules/@angular/core
  peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@13.0.0
  node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
    @angular/material-moment-adapter@"^13.0.0" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^1.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "ng2-charts": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "12.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

I use:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.9
Node: 16.10.0
Package Manager: npm 9.1.1
OS: win32 x64
```

Should I install Angular 10.0.5 and node.js 10.13.0 to build this project?

Answer (score 1):

If you check your `package.json`, you can see that all Angular dependencies are Angular `v10`. So, you should install the same version of Material:

```js
ng add @angular/material@10
```

---

Also, based on the `package.json`, Material is already added to the project. If you have to use the newer version of Material, you should first upgrade you project to that version. You can followed [Angular official guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-11.0) for upgrading the project.

**Note:** It is recommended to upgrade one version at a time.